# Javascript document load bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below in which I've added 1 alert at the start and one at the end.

I get the first alert but the last alert never pops up.

Can anyone see why ?

Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('start');  
        var month = getURLParameter('month') - 1; //-1 cause javascript months start in 0
   var currentYear = getURLParameter('year');
   var defaultDate = new Date(currentYear, month, 1); //Set to first day of the month
   $("#date").datepicker({ defaultDate: defaultDate });
  alert('end');

    });

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get in the error console?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for errors. Especially without knowing your `getURLParameter` function we cannot debug your code.

Comment: Don't use alerts to debug your javascript code. Use FireBug and watch the console.

Comment: I get: Error: getURLParameter is not defined

Comment: `<script language="javascript">`? Why are you writing HTML 3.2?

Comment: I'm going to change the title `load bag` to "bug", even though it's funnier this way :)

Comment: just to add my solution: I had a typo instead of `getURLParameter` I used `getURLparameter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that `getURLParameter` is not defined or there is an error with it.

It could be that `datepicker()` is not available either.

This works in the jsfiddle demo with a placeholder function for `getURLParameter` and jquery UI loaded:

http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/bwJGS/